# How do I connect to a remote docker daemon without being root?

Tags: docker

I have a server running the docker daemon exposing port 2375 (yes, this is naughty, but I'm looking at getting the simplest set-up working before doing things properly).

I can connect to the remote server as root:

```
➜  ~ export DOCKER_HOST=72.333.194.99:2375
➜  ~ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://72.333.194.99:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
➜  ~ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED                 STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
➜  ~
```

The above example is for brevity, I can build images and run containers on my remote server using local source files.

How can I do the same without being root?

I have set up the docker group on my server, so when I'm in the server I do not need to be sudo. I have a single user on my server with the name 'root'.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're talking to the remote server?  [By default `sudo` resets the process environment](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.25/sudoers.man.html#Command_environment) and so `sudo docker ps` is probably talking to a local Docker, via a socket, as root.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a server running the docker daemon exposing port 2375 (yes, this is naughty, but I'm looking at getting the simplest set-up working before doing things properly).

This isn't naughty, it's dangerous. It means you have remote root shell access to your host, unencrypted, without a password, on a well known and scanned for protocol. If you've actually set this up like this, then most likely by the time you're reading this answer your server has already been hacked and you should reinstall your entire OS to be safe.

> I can connect to the remote server as root:
>
> ```
> ➜  ~ export DOCKER_HOST=72.333.194.99:2375
> ➜  ~ docker ps
> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://72.333.194.99:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
> ➜  ~ sudo docker ps
> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED                 STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
> ➜  ~
> ```

You have not connected to the remote server in either docker command. First, you did not give a valid IP address. 333 is outside of the valid range. And the second sudo command runs in a root shell, with a different environment, so it is most likely your local docker install that you saw with that command. You can run `sudo docker info` to see this.

> How do I connect to a remote docker daemon without being root?

Docker is a client/server application. The remote server does not know your local user id when connecting over TCP, so eliminate that from the equation. The reason you need to have root access locally, or be a member of the docker group, is because docker locks down access to `/var/run/docker.sock` with those permissions. If you have not configured the remote server to listen on the network (hopefully), then you can follow this procedure to configure a private CA with TLS keys for the server and client:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

If you deviate from these instructions, and simply expose the socket without TLS, or do not configure mutual TLS authentication of both the client and the server, then you effectively have a remote root login to the server without a password, so do take care to follow all of the steps.

---

If you do not want to configure mutual TLS, 18.09 is currently in beta with the option to connect to a remote docker server over ssh: https://blog.docker.com/2018/09/join-the-beta-for-docker-engine-18-09/

```
$ docker -H ssh://me@example.com info
```

or

```
$ export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://me@example.com
$ docker info
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to a remote Daemon running on any server machine please follow the below steps.
Identify the Host machine where the Docker Client is running.
If the Docker **Client Machine is a Linux Machine**. Please run the below command that connects to the remote docker Daemon.

```
export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://administrator@10.242.41.222
```

The above command will establish the ssh connection to the remote machine and all the docker command get executed on the remote machine.

If the **Docker Client Machine is a Windows Machine**. Please run the below command to obtain the same result as above.

```
$env:DOCKER_HOST="ssh://administrator@10.242.41.222"
```

If one wants the **docker client to use the old Docker daemon** running on the client server. Please reset the value of the environment variable to empty.

**In WIN :** $env:DOCKER_HOST=" " 
**In Linux :** export DOCKER_HOST=' '

Answer (score -2):

it seems that your user that executes the docker command is not in the docker daemon group,

you can add it by code below :

**NOTE**: RUN AS USER THAT HAS THE ISSUE.

`sudo usermod -a -G docker $(whoami)`

after that ,for applying changes ,user must sign out and sign in again.

Comment: please attention to the title of the question! try to connect remote not local!