# ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: The requested URL /v1.25/info was not found on this server

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to set up gitlab CI on a windows 10 PC.

I have created a docker container for gitlab and another for the runner. Everything seems to be OK till i execute the pipeline.

After these experiments [ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422889/error-job-failed-system-failure-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix/59438682#59438682)

I have tried to configure my runner following the posts here :

[How to connect to docker host from container on Windows 10 (Docker for Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746453/how-to-connect-to-docker-host-from-container-on-windows-10-docker-for-windows)

I tested :

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Runner des tests unitaires"
  url = "http://11.22.33.44:4480/"
  token = "my_secret_token"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    host = "tcp://docker.for.win.localhost"
...
```

and

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Runner des tests unitaires"
  url = "http://11.22.33.44:4480/"
  token = "my_secret_token"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    host = "tcp://10.0.75.1"
...
```

I changed my .gitlab-ci.yml accordingly :

```
variables:
    HELLO: World
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker.for.win.localhost

test:
    script:
        - echo $HELLO
```

But i still have an error when executing the pipeline :

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /v1.25/info was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html> (executor_docker.go:980:0s)
```

I feel that now, the containers can talk together but where does this /v1.25/info URL comes from ?

I don't understand the meaning of this error message...

My config

```
Docker Desktop Community edition 2.0.0.3 (Engine 18.09.2)
GitLab Community Edition 12.5.2
Gitlab Runner 12.5.0
Windows 10.0.17763
```